# Is there a way to close the focused window when cycling in xfce4?

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, desktop-environment

It happens a lot that I end up having 20+ windows opened and closing them one by one, when selecting them from the *cycle window*, takes a lot of time. So is there a shortcut (or a way, at least), e.g. `alt + tab + BUTTON` that does it?

Comment: you can easily create custom shortcuts with `xbindkeys`

Comment: @IporSircer sure, that is not exactly the question. Is there a possibility to that in the first place?